# How to refactor away asynchronous duplicate code

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, refactoring

I have the following code snippet and I want to refactor (make a function) from the duplicated code.

```
function add(logger, client, args, callback) {

    client.execute('some command', args, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            logger.error({err: err});
            return callback(err);
        }

        // do more...


        logger.debug({result: result});
        return callback(null, result);
    });
}
```

All of my asynchronous calls to client.execute have the inner callback duplicated. I want to pull that up and make a function out of it. so it needs to take parameters, logger and a callback function.

How do I make a function out of that?
After that what would the function add look like?

Comment: Why do you return anything at all in the errback?

Comment: can you rephrase your question please? I am not understanding what you are asking

Comment: `return callback(err);` - what is the point in returning this value? Does `callback` return anything meaningful? Is the async function using this return value?

Comment: oh the add function itself. Yes it has to be this way due to the existing framework that this function fits into. There is an outer async.series that the add function is called from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you slightly changed the order in your code, you could refactor it like this:

```
function logAndCallback(err, result, callback) {
    if (err) {
        logger.error({err: err});
        return callback(err);
    }
    logger.debug({result: result});
    return callback(null, result);
}

function add(logger, client, args, callback) {

    client.execute('some command', args, function (err, result) {
        if (!err) {
          // do more...
        }

        return logAndCallback(err, result, callback);
    });
}
```

Comment: I have omitted a lot of details, to keep things clear... Having said, I can use the approach you are recommending and with minor changes, does answer my question. I appreciate your help.